# Jquery ui tabs slow with large amount of data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have noticed, that when using jQuery UI tabs layout and I have opened some tabs in which is bigger amount of HTML. Then whitching between tabs is a bit slow. Like when I click on tab label it takes for example 2-4 seconds until the tab opens. I thik that's a fact and I can't change it if I want such a long texts to disply in my tabs, but is there a way to show some loading indicator before the tab is opened?

Comment: "is there a way to show some loading indicator before the tab is opened?" Sure, what have you tried?

Comment: 2-4 seconds implies you have a LOT of HTML. How big are we talking here?

Comment: @j08691 I have n problem with showing that indicator bsetting click event on tab lbels, but I don't know how to hide it, affter the tab is swtched. I have tried `$(window).load(function () {});` but it didn't work.

Comment: @MikeRobinson the most of my documents are small, but the biggest can be up to 3 MB big

Comment: 3 MB of document is a lot of data, especially if you're using more browser heavy elements (for example, lots of radio buttons). Regardless, it sounds like the hang time is just from the browser trying to put everything on the page. Could you lazy load some of the content instead of dumping it out all at once?

Comment: I know that it's a lot of data, but it is a simple text, only format tags and links. So the problem is not with loading that data, but the problem is when I am swithicng tabs (making this amount of data visible or inivsible)

Comment: I found the jsFiddle code that show a message (loading indicator). Is it answering your question ?

Answer (score 3):

not my code, it's from jQuery forum:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/switching-tabs-slow-with-big-content

The code is at :

http://jsfiddle.net/7npbK/1/

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({
      beforeActivate: function () {
          // alert("switching");
          $("#loadingDiv").fadeIn('slow');
      },
      activate: function () {
          //alert("switched");
          $("#loadingDiv").fadeOut('slow');
      }
  });
```

Basically, you make use of **beforeActivate** and **activate** events of the jQuery UI tabs.
However, it does not fix the root cause: jQuery tabs make use of CSS show/hide, and with a large number of DOM elements, it cause slow UI response.

Comment: This doesn't help, the indicator does't show up until the tabs are switched. But I have stopped using jQuery UI due to its bad performance with big data.

Comment: So, which JavaScript component are you using now ? Have you tried the Bootstrap tabs : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage ?

Comment: I have created my own tabs optimized for my data :)